# hibernate annotated native update to one column

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying update one column to null, but it gives me error. I done this taking data to variable and then resetting it. But I am interesting why this don't worked:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value="UPDATE fact_header SET fact_id=null WHERE id=:ids", nativeQuery=true)
public void updateAssignedFact(@Param("ids") int id);
```

I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

I saw some hints about Transactions. I am using 2 databases.

Edit, this code worked:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional /* just added this line */
@Query(value="UPDATE fact_header SET fact_id=null WHERE id=:ids", nativeQuery=true)
public void updateAssignedFact(@Param("ids") int id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must need a transaction.

Depending on your specific environment there are different ways of doing this:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions

You'll begin the transaction before the call to updateAssignedFact and end it afterwards. Possibly including other operations; I don't know exactly what you are doing. I don't think you can (or should) try to deal with the transaction inside the data entity class.

Comment: I am using spring-data-jpa and this code is in repository. transaction is make. I can do Select, but not update.

Comment: Have you tried putting the @Transactional annotation on your DAO?

Comment: @Transactional( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW )

Comment: Yes @Transactional exists. I will try add propagation to it.

Comment: Thank you @danpaq for help. I added @ Transactional and it worked. Question updated.